# Angular 2. Disable the button when the user enters or pastes the spaces in the textbox

Tags: angular, validation, button, textbox

Am using ngForm for validating the textbox but its allowing me to enter the space. I need button to be disabled when the user enters or pastes the **SPACES** in the textbox. I tried some solutions from previous stack overflow answers but nothing worked. How can I achieve this?

```
<form #SearchForm="ngForm">
    <input kendoTextBox name="SearchByEmail" [(ngModel)]="searchByEmail" required />
    <button class="crud-buttons" kendoButton [primary]="true" [disabled]="!SearchForm.valid">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try pattern?

Comment: am not getting correct pattern

Answer (score 0):

We can use **(keydown.space)="$event.preventDefault();**

```
<input name="SearchByEmail" [(ngModel)]="searchByEmail" (keydown.space)="$event.preventDefault();" required />
```

This will not allow to enter space bar.